# Implementation of popular algorithms in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search, sorting

Can anybody suggest a good book or website which explains all popular search/sort/tree/Graph algorithms using JavaScript?

I am looking for something like the book introduction to algorithms, but providing implementation examples and code snippets in JavaScript rather than in Pseudo code or C/Java etc.

The purpose is to learn the basic computer science algorithms in JavaScript because I like and understand JavaScript better.

Comment: Algorithms as basic as those are language agnostic. Learn those and JS independent of each other, then apply them simultaneously. I doubt anyone has written a book catering to a market as specific as `Javascript implementations of popular search/sort/tree/Graph algorithms`

Comment: @Asad There is a book by O'Reilly called "Data Structures and Algorithms with JavaScript" coming in March 2014

Comment: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920029557.do

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This repository will help you https://github.com/mgechev/javascript-algorithms.